# Vivado HLS class with member of type hls::stream<int>& leads to error: "Constant '' has an unsynthesizable type ..."

Tags: c++, vivado-hls

I'm trying to see if it is possible to instantiate a class in vivado_hls that has hls::stream<> reference members so that I can directly read/write the stream without having to pass the stream as an argument down the call chain.

NOTE: This is in vivado_hls 2018.2 and the top level module for this project is "ModuleX"
Consider the simplified scenario below:

```
#include <hls_stream.h>
#include <ap_int.h>

using hls_int = ap_uint<32>;

class X
{
  private:
    hls::stream<hls_int> &s1;
    hls::stream<hls_int> &s2;

  public:
    X(hls::stream<hls_int> &_s1, hls::stream<hls_int> &_s2) :
        s1(_s1), s2(_s2)
    {}

    void Run()
    {
        hls_int s = s2.read();
        hls_int out = s * 2;
        s1.write(out);
    }
};

void ModuleX(hls::stream<hls_int> &s1, hls::stream<hls_int> &s2)
{
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_ctrl_none PORT=return
    #pragma HLS STREAM VARIABLE=s1 DEPTH=1
    #pragma HLS STREAM VARIABLE=s2 DEPTH=1

    static X x {s1, s2};

    x.Run();
}
```

With this approach, I get the following error: `ERROR: [SYNCHK 200-11] ClassWithStreamRefs.cpp:18: Constant 'x.s2.V.V' has an unsynthesizable type 'i32P*' (possible cause(s): pointer to pointer or global pointer).`

I understand that under-the-hood, the compiler is probably storing the reference as a pointer-to the stream, but that should be a bug with the tooling for this scenario as far as I'm considered since it is blocking, what I see as valid HLS.

Hopefully there is another way to implement what I'm looking for (references, not values are stored in the class).

Something else I tried that worked is below. However, it's highly undesirable because the approach adds 2 clock cycles of latency (1 each at the ingress and egress - for no good reason).

```
#include <hls_stream.h>
#include <ap_int.h>

using hls_int = ap_uint<32>;

class X
{
  public:
    hls::stream<hls_int> s1;
    hls::stream<hls_int> s2;
    X()
    {
        #pragma HLS STREAM VARIABLE=s1 DEPTH=1
        #pragma HLS STREAM VARIABLE=s2 DEPTH=1
    }

    void Run()
    {
        hls_int s = s2.read();
        hls_int out = s * 2;
        s1.write(out);
    }
};

void ModuleX(hls::stream<hls_int> &s1, hls::stream<hls_int> &s2)
{
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_ctrl_none PORT=return
    #pragma HLS INLINE
    static X x;

    x.s2.write(s2.read());
    x.Run();
    s1.write(x.s1.read());
}
```

Here's a sample tcl script (although it's basically just autogenerated by vivado_hls)

```
open_project ClassWithStreamRef
set_top ModuleX
add_files ClassWithStreamRefs.cpp -cflags "-std=c++11"
open_solution "solution1"
set_part {xczu19eg-ffvc1760-2-i} -tool vivado
create_clock -period 10 -name default
csynth_design
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the underlying mechanism, but removing the `static` qualifier allows Vivado HLS 2018.2 to synthesize the example. This however makes a new instance of `X` on every top function invocation, so its fields do not persist. The example below solves that by adding another static variable in the top function for persistence and passing it by reference to `X`'s constructor.

```
#include <hls_stream.h>
#include <ap_int.h>

using hls_int = ap_uint<32>;

struct State
{
    hls_int counter;
};

class X
{
  private:
    hls::stream<hls_int> &s1;
    hls::stream<hls_int> &s2;
    State& state;

  public:
    X(hls::stream<hls_int> &_s1, hls::stream<hls_int> &_s2, State& _state) :
        s1(_s1), s2(_s2), state(_state)
    {}

    void Run()
    {
        hls_int s = s2.read();
        s1.write(s + state.counter++);
    }
};

void ModuleX(hls::stream<hls_int> &s1, hls::stream<hls_int> &s2)
{
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_ctrl_none PORT=return
    #pragma HLS STREAM VARIABLE=s1 DEPTH=1
    #pragma HLS STREAM VARIABLE=s2 DEPTH=1

    static State state {0};
    X x {s1, s2, state};

    x.Run();
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this does seem to get some of my scenarios to synthesize. However, I hope that this doesn't cause the "object"/module to lose state between ap_start signals or between cycles.
Base on UG902 (v.2018.2, pg.382) the provided example of class instantiation specifies the static keyword: `static CFir<coef_t, data_t, acc_t> fir1;`. I assume this is to persist state of the "object"/module, but I don't see the UG make any mention of _why_ either way. I'll get back to this about whether or not the static keyword affects module state persistence in this case. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I believe that you're right, and using a non-static object will not persist state between ap_start signals. Perhaps you can try putting the persistent state in a different variable that you can then pass to the X object's Run() method or to its constructor.

Comment: It seems like this behaviour (not supporting stream refs in this case) is probably a bug on Vivado's end, so I think your second suggestion is the approach I will take. If you can include that comment content (in case anyone else has this problem) in your answer I will accept it :) Thank you